# jQuery Resizable's "also resize" no longer working - what can turn it off?

Tags: jquery, image, resize, dimensions

I have a div with class `.box` which contains an image, and I used:

```
$thebox = $('.box');
$thebox.resizable({ handles: 'all', alsoResize: img_id});
```

To resize the contained image when the div is resized. The image has its own source and ID, so the HTML is something like this:

```
<div class='box'><img src='path/filename' id='img1' /></div>
```

Then at one point, (at the user's edit), I replace the source of the image, to replace the image with a new one. But after the replacement of the image, the `box` container continues to be able to be resized as expected, however, the contained `img1` is now no longer getting resized in sync, it remains static as it is. I have no idea why this is happening!

### Edit

Okay so I got an error on Firebug saying `TypeError: a.size is undefined`, and the relevant jQuery is this:

```
function(a){e(a)});else e(g.alsoResize)},resize:function(g,e){var a=b(this).data("resizable");g=a.options;var d=a.originalSize,h=a.originalPosition,i={height:a.size.height-d.height||0,width:a.size.width-d.width||0,top:a.position.top-h.top||0,l..... // blah blah
```

Does that help any?

Comment: You should re-init the resize, that image is a different node it seems

Comment: That is step forward but there's no info here on how is this relevant to the problem, there might be a connection but it might be a totally different issue. Try creating a fiddle so that other can examine the code in details or put breakpoints and debug in your browser

Answer (score 0):

You should re-init the resize, that image is a different node it seems.The reference is broken.

When changing the `src` do that again

```
$thebox.resizable({ handles: 'all', alsoResize: img_id});
```

Comment: I tried it, it didn't make a difference. So I tried turning resize off using "option" , "disabled", and then turning it on again. But how do we completely remove the resizable binding with the object?

Comment: How about you destroy it first `$thebox.resizable( "destroy" );` then change the `src` and init it again. Also are you positive that there are no js errors?

Comment: Yes I tried... and no there are no other errors. Is there any way to trace what's happening within jQuery and why it's not grabbing this image? This image does in fact exist with the ID as mentioned, but I don't know what else to check. I just edited the question - jQuery does seem to be complaining about something when I do the same action the second time with another image.

Comment: Try providing a jsfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/, also you could try some debugging